# I am new to Boolean Algebra, and i need advice

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

Simplified the boolean expression: A'BC + A'BC' + AC

This is what I came up with:

```
A'BC + A'BC' + AC
= A'(BC + BC') + AC
= A'B(1) + AC 
= A'B + AC
```

As mentioned in the post title, I am new to boolean algebra. What I need to know is if I am correct, and can I simplify the expression further. Is there a better boolean law to use?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!